# Expression for a situation where you are too used to your work that you don't see its beauty/potential

Tags: expressions

I am working on my first production mobile app (Android). The UI is okay (to me), but when I show my friends they are amazed by it and tell me how beautiful it is. Since I'm the one creating it and I see it every other minute, it is understandable that I have gotten used it that it's just, ordinary. What do you call this? I know it is also something people in arts experience.Is there a name for it?

Comment: Something along the lines of [_familiarity breeds contempt_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/familiarity-breeds-contempt)?

Comment: No, that kinda means you get too close to someone and they no longer respect you.

Comment: No, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/familiarity-breeds-contempt) licenses Gnawme's sense also: 'Familiarity is used especially in the expression familiarity breeds contempt to say that if you know a person or situation very well, you can easily lose respect for that person or become careless in that situation.'

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.But I think @NIkki's perfectly describes what am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Blasé](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blas%C3%A9).
Also according to [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/blase):

> **Blasé** : **Adjective**
>   not excited, worried, or enthusiastic about something that most people think is exciting, worrying, or impressive, because you have done it many times before

*You are getting blasé about your creation.*

Comment: "having or showing a lack of excitement or interest in something especially because it is very familiar"...This is it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you would describe this situation as [you can't see the forest for the trees.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/can-t-see-the-forest-for-the-trees) (dictionary.com)

> An expression used of someone who is too involved in the details of a problem to look at the situation as a whole

This expression does have a bit of a negative connotation, but I think in this case it's not too negative for what you've described.

Comment: I think it's something along that line.Major difference is this isn't a problem am trying to solve.I've just gotten too close to something that I no longer appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't readily find a reference for it, but what you're looking for may be *too close to see it* and variants. You need other sets of eyes to help you see what you have lost the ability to see by virtue of being too invested in something or having been over the same ground too many times. I have used and heard this term often in connection with the development of documents, which are analogous to your UIs. Getting external feedback early and often, long before you lose the ability *to see* whatever it is you're producing, is key to success.

Comment: I'll agree with that, Richard, but I'm also aware that the originator of something (whether its a work of art, a utilitarian object, a piece of software or even a performance) is often aware of flaws or weaknesses in the product that other people, not being so closely involved, do not perceive.

Comment: @BoldBen True. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You've plainly become [*insensible*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/insensible?s=t) to the beauty and uniqueness of your creation (sense 3):

> 3. unaware; unconscious; inappreciative: *We are not insensible of your kindness.*

Answer (score 2):

A few possibilities spring to mind:

> - [objectivize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/objectivization): To make objective or impersonal; objectify

Your first production mobile app is something you have objectivized, at least for the time being, since you are in the process of bringing it into being. Naturally, you need to step back and ask questions such as, How can I improve it?; What is wrong with it?; and Is the cost of making it available prohibitive?

> - to [take for granted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+for+granted): to underestimate the value of: a publisher who took the editors for granted.

To take something (or someone) for granted means in your case that you are temporarily underestimating the value of your mobile app until you consider it a viable and sellable commodity (in other words, ready for the marketplace).

> - to become [habituated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/habituated): the process by which one becomes accustomed by frequent repetition or prolonged exposure.

Habituation need not necessarily be a bad thing. Habituation causes you to see and do things over and over again--as with the application of the scientific method to some undertaking, for example--so as to keep your feelings, which can often prove distracting and unproductive, in check.

> - to become [oblivious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oblivious) to: lacking conscious awareness; unmindful: *oblivious* to her surroundings; *oblivious* of the criticism against him

I insert this word as a possibility, since you seem to lack conscious awareness of the felicities surrounding this "app" you're currently working on. True enough, some developers or inventors become enamored with their app much too soon. Consequently they find objectivity vis a vis their "baby" difficult to assume. In your case, however, you seem to be keeping your distance from subjectivity and pride in your accomplishments until you've finished your masterpiece.

Answer (score 2):

you are ***jaded***.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded)

> 2. made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by having or seeing too much of something

Example (made up):

> After four weeks in the Seychelles, I was jaded and oblivious to its
>   extreme beauty; the real world was an enormous shock when I returned
>   to it.

If you have to go back to an earlier version of your app, you will be in shock too.